# Access a remote Windows shared folder from Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, shared-folders

I am a Windows intermediate user and I have recently installed Linux Mint 13 Maya 32-bit version on my laptop. Earlier my major activities in my Windows box were:

- Connecting to internet, wifi, VPN etcetera
- Doing RDC
- Accessing shared folders.

I am able to achieve the first 2 things. The last one, I am puzzled as how to access a Windows shared folder from my Linux Mint laptop.

Note: There is no Virtual box here. My laptop has only Linux mint. I am just trying to access a remote windows shared folder.

In windows I used to do this.

> Goto run and type the command
>
> ```
>  \\<system name>
> ```

Here, how can I do that? Any simple way or tools?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your network is properly configured, you should be able to just click on the server name from your file manager:

[image]

In the best case scenario, roperly configured" just means you have run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

For more information, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (mint 17):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //1.1.1.1/shared -o username=USER,password=PASS /home/user/mnt/
```

Answer (score 1):

With the proper filesystem driver, you can mount Windows SMB shares as with any other type of remote fileshare; I gather Mint calls the package `cifs-tools`, and once installed you should be able to do something approximating `mount -t cifs '\\path\to\share' /mnt/share` and get the expected result.

For a more FTP/SFTP-style interface, there's also `smbclient`, which is probably packaged under that name or something close to it. If you only need to grab a file off the share every now and then, `smbclient` may suffice; for any more frequent usage than that, I definitely recommend installing `cifs-tools` and mounting the share.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using NFS and CIFS for decade(s)... but I ran into an issue where I could not get a volume mounted through normal CIFS...

I found a utility called SMB4K that is a package you can install.

[image: smb4k screen shot]

Works like a dream.  Mounts the CIFS under your home directory and puts an icon down in your menubar that allows you to control it.

Works like a dream.  I use it under MINT (with UBUNTU).  Auto-starts and auto-mounts every time I restart my workstation.

Cheers!
-D